# Is "make it rain" hat awarded for bounties on the meta?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I set up a bounty on one of my questions on meta. Are bounties on questions on meta eligible for the "make it rain" hat?

Comment: Yes, they are eligible

Comment: and do automatically awarded(half rep) bounties count?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, when you award the bounty you get the hat.

Comment: I've got my hat for awarding bounty at MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/211413/revisions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not matter on what site you set up a bounty. You get the *Make it rain* hat when you award that bounty to someone.

(BTW for the *Millner* hat you need 20 hats on the same site.)